# $a_1=3$ and $a_{n+1}=\dfrac{2a_n}{3}+\dfrac{4}{3a_n^2}$. Show that $4^{1/3} \le a_n$for all $1\le n$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

$a_1=3$ and $a_{n+1}=\dfrac{2a_n}{3}+\dfrac{4}{3a_n^2}$

By considering the function $f(x)=\dfrac{2x}{3}+\dfrac{4}{3x^2}$, show that $4^{1/3} \le a_n$ for all $1\le n$.

Comment: For all $n\leq1$?

Comment: @P.. fixed it ~

Comment: What about $n=1$? $a_1=3>4^{\frac13}$

Comment: @P.. Oh, I mean $4^{1/3} \le a_n$

Comment: if we note the formula carefully it is a recursive procedure to find cube root of $4$. This is derived from Newton Raphson formula for root of $f(x) = x^{3} - 4 = 0$. If $a_{n}$ is an approximation to the root then $a_{n + 1} = a_{n} - \dfrac{f(a_{n})}{f'(a_{n})}$ is a better approximation to the root.

Comment: If one understands the logic of the Newton raphson and nature of graph of $f(x) = x^{3} - 4$ near and to the right of point of $x = 4^{1/3}$ (it is convex there) then the result becomes obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f'(x)=\dfrac{2}{3}-\dfrac{8}{3x^3}=0 \implies x=4^{\frac{1}{3}}$ it is easy to verify this is min point when$x>0$ ,so $f_{min}=4^{\frac{1}{3}}$

$a_n$ is belong to $f(x)$ so $a_n \ge  4^{\frac{1}{3}}$